# Unresolved Error in Django Model Testing

Tags: django, django-testing

```
from django.test import TestCase
from .models import Publisher

class PublisherModelTestCase(TestCase):
    def setUp(self):
        Publisher.objects.create(name = 'some random test title',website = 'cn@gmail.com')

    def test_publisher_title(self):
        obj = Publisher.objects.get(website = 'cn@gmail.com')
        self.assertEqual(obj.name,'some random test title')

    def test_str_representation(self):
        obj = Publisher.objects.get(name='some random test titile')
        self.assertEqual(obj,obj.__str__())
```

I have created this testcase for my Model, but despite of working in python shell, its showing error when i run the above code. Please be correcting me where am i doing wrong..

models.py

```
class Publisher(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=30)
    address = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    city = models.CharField(max_length=60)
    state_province = models.CharField(max_length=30)
    country = models.CharField(max_length=50)
    website = models.URLField(blank=True)

    class Meta:
        ordering = ["-name"]

    def __str__(self):
        return self.name
```

Its saying object which i am creating through `setUp` function doesnt exist.But in python shell its creating the object with same values.

```
ERROR: test_publisher_title (cbv.tests.PublisherModelTestCase)
----------------------------------------------------------------------
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "D:\django\blog_env\mysite\cbv\tests.py", line 13, in test_publisher_title
    obj = Publisher.objects.get(website = 'cn@gmail.com')
  File "D:\django\blog_env\lib\site-packages\django\db\models\manager.py", line 82, in manager_method
    return getattr(self.get_queryset(), name)(*args, **kwargs)
  File "D:\django\blog_env\lib\site-packages\django\db\models\query.py", line 403, in get
    self.model._meta.object_name
cbv.models.DoesNotExist: Publisher matching query does not exist.

======================================================================
ERROR: test_str_representation (cbv.tests.PublisherModelTestCase)
----------------------------------------------------------------------
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "D:\django\blog_env\mysite\cbv\tests.py", line 17, in test_str_representation
    obj = Publisher.objects.get(name='some random test titile')
  File "D:\django\blog_env\lib\site-packages\django\db\models\manager.py", line 82, in manager_method
    return getattr(self.get_queryset(), name)(*args, **kwargs)
  File "D:\django\blog_env\lib\site-packages\django\db\models\query.py", line 403, in get
    self.model._meta.object_name
cbv.models.DoesNotExist: Publisher matching query does not exist.

----------------------------------------------------------------------
Ran 4 tests in 0.595s

FAILED (errors=2)
```

So,i changed `get()` to `filter()` and corrected my query to `'....title'` but now new error occurs..

```
ERROR: test_publisher_title (cbv.tests.PublisherModelTestCase)
----------------------------------------------------------------------
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "D:\django\blog_env\mysite\cbv\tests.py", line 14, in test_publisher_title
    self.assertEqual(obj.name,'some random test title')
AttributeError: 'QuerySet' object has no attribute 'name'

======================================================================
ERROR: test_str_representation (cbv.tests.PublisherModelTestCase)
----------------------------------------------------------------------
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "D:\django\blog_env\mysite\cbv\tests.py", line 18, in test_str_representation
    self.assertEqual(obj.name,obj.__str__())
AttributeError: 'QuerySet' object has no attribute 'name'

----------------------------------------------------------------------
Ran 4 tests in 0.152s

FAILED (errors=2)
```

Comment: Well the error explains it. There is no `Publisher` that matches `Publisher.objects.get(name='some random test titile')`, so it raises an error.

Comment: means there is no Publisher Model to match? @WillemVanOnsem

Comment: filter or get should not matter because you are creating the object in setup() check if setup() is called and check if this line is throwing up any errors! Publisher.objects.create(name = 'some random test title',website = 'cn@gmail.com')

Comment: @Nagashayan yes, sir, `Publisher.objects.create(name = 'some random test title',website = 'cn@gmail.com'` is creating queryset in its default database, but it cant able to access it other two test cases..

Comment: try this and let me know what happens - remove create() from setup() and add it to both test_funct(), the first one should run properly, second one should fail throwing duplicate key.

Answer (score 0):

This error is because your query using `.get()` is empty. `.get()` will return an error if the query is either empty or contain more than one result. Use `.filter()` instead with proper conditions.

See [doc](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.0/topics/db/queries/#retrieving-a-single-object-with-get).

When `.get()` returns an object directly, `filter()` returns a queryset so you have to check if the queryset is empty and then use `queryset.first()` or `queryset[0]`.

Another solution is to wrap your `.get()` in a try/except block:

```
try:
    obj = Publisher.objects.get(website = 'cn@gmail.com')
except:
    # No Publisher was found for this website
    # Do something
```

Comment: ok,i changed it to filter but it still showing some error..i updating so in my question..please have a look.

Answer (score 0):

Change

`obj = Publisher.objects.get(name='some random test titile')`

to

`obj = Publisher.objects.get(name='some random test title')`

Comment: If you use `filter` it has to be something like `obj = Publisher.objects.filter(name='some random test title')[0]`. You need to access an Publisher instance.